# Periodic Cross-Correlation vs Aperiodic Cross-Correlation

Tags: time-series, references, terminology, cross-correlation, definition

I am doing research in spread spectrum communication, and many papers frequently use the terms Periodic Cross-Correlation and Aperiodic Cross-Correlation. However, I cannot find a clear definition of these terms and their differences between them.

Also, what is the definition of Odd Cross-Correlation?

Could you also identify some books or papers that clearly define them?

Comment: Asking people to "share their thoughts" would make your question off topic anywhere (it would close as unclear or too broad), since it invites all manner of divergent answers. Please edit to ask a specific question without such an invitation.

Comment: @Glen_b I think the question is pretty clear in this case: First, what is the definition of Periodic Cross-Correlation and Aperiodic Cross-Correlation and secondly,  what is the definition of Odd Cross-Correlation. It doesn't really get simpler than that. I don't how else should I rephrase my question!

Comment: Please note that it closed as *too broad*, not as unclear; your feeling about its clarity don't relate to why it closed. I have attempted an edit that does something like I asked you to do. Feel free to edit again to more closely reflect your intent, but please be careful to avoid going back to where you started.

Comment: This question would be a far better fit on dsp.SE than here.

Comment: See the paper D.V.Sarwate and M.B.Pursley, "Crosscorrelation properties of pseudorandom and related sequences," _Proceedings of the IEEE_, vol. 68, pp. 593-619, May 1980. It is, unfortunately, behind IEEE's paywall but free copies can be found in some repositories.